# Error install module barcodes_generator_abstract in odoo12

Tags: python, odoo

I got an error each time I try to install the `barcodes_generator_abstract` module in Odoo 12.

> Unable to install module "barcodes_generator_abstract" because an external 
>   dependency is not met: No module named barcode

Comment: **pip install python-barcode**  
Requirement already satisfied: python-barcode in c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages (0.10.0)

Comment: as the error said, you need another module called "barcode" before installing the module barcodes_generator because it is not in your system yet I guess

Comment: put full name in external dependency i.e. python-barcode

Comment: still error gues... just info : i'm install this module from source : https://github.com/OCA/stock-logistics-barcode/tree/12.0/barcodes_generator_abstract